# Get Children common to All Parents

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have the following Entities using Entity Framework Core:

```
public class Parent {
  public Int32 ParentId { get; set; }
  public virtual Collection<ParentChildren> ParentChildrens { get; set; }
}

public class ParentChildren {
  public Int32 ParentId { get; set; }
  public Int32 ChildrenId { get; set; }
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
  public virtual Children Children { get; set; }
}

public class Children {
  public Int32 ChildrenId { get; set; }
  public virtual Collection<ParentChildren> ParentChildrens { get; set; }
  public virtual Collection<ChildrenLocalization> ChildrenLocalizations { get; set; }
}

public class ChildrenLocalization {
  public Int32 ChildrenId { get; set; }
  public String Language { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Children Children { get; set; }
}
```

Given a `IQueryable<Parent>` I need to, using Linq to Entities lambda expressions:

1. **Get the Children common to all Parents**;
2. For each `Children` get its name from `ChildrenLocalization` with `Language="en"`.

So I tried the following:

```
var result = context.Parents
  .SelectMany(y => y.ParentChildrens)
  .GroupBy(y => y.ParentId)
  .Where(y => 
     context.Parents
       .SelectMany(y => y.ParentChildrens)
       .Select(z => z.ChildrenId)
       .Distinct()
       .All(z => y.Any(w => w.ChildrenId == z)))
  .SelectMany(y => y)
  .Select(y => new {
    Id = y.ChildrenId,
    Name = y.Children.ChildrenLocalizations.Where(z => z.Language == "en").Select(z => z.Name).FirstOrDefault()
  })
  .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
  .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
  .ToList();
```

**This query is giving the expected result** but it seems too complex.

I wasn't able to improve it and, for example, I needed the add the last GroupBy to make it work.

How can I make my query simpler?

Comment: Just one question. Dose this creates a single sql statement? And did you profile it for performance?

Comment: No, it creates multiple SQL statements and some are evaluated in memory. That is why I am trying to improve it ...

Comment: "Get the Children common to all Parents" Does it mean: get all Children that have every Parent in its collection of Parents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have many-to-many relationship, it's better to base (start) the query on the resulting entity (`Children`), thus avoiding the need of `GroupBy` /`Distinct` if you start it from the other end (`Parent`).

So given

```
IQueryable<Parent> parents
```

and assuming you have access to the context, the query can be written as follows:

```
var query = context.Set<Children>()
    .Where(c => parents.All(p => p.ParentChildrens.Select(pc => pc.ChildrenId).Contains(c.ChildrenId)))
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Id = c.ChildrenId,
        Name = c.ChildrenLocalizations.Where(cl => cl.Language == "en").Select(cl => cl.Name).FirstOrDefault()
    });
```

which nicely translates to a single SQL.

You start with *unique* `Children`. For requirement (2) you simply use the navigation property. The requirement (1) is more complicated (*all* is always harder to achieve than *any*), but I think the criteria

```
parents.All(p => p.ParentChildrens.Select(pc => pc.ChildrenId).Contains(c.ChildrenId))
```

quite intuitively represents *child common to all parents*.

Comment: perfect use of `All` and `Contains` (y)

Comment: question: will `c.ChildrenLocalizations.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.Language == "en").Name` also work? for some reason it doesn't throw even when `FirstOrDefault` returns `null`

Comment: @PaoloGo It will work if the query is translated and executed server side (SQL). It will start throwing NRE if for some reason it switches to client evaluation. These are some of the differences / inconsistencies between the two modes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood this correctly this might work. This will be a single query.

```
    var result =
            (from parent in context.Parents
            from pToC in parent.ParentChildrens
            where pToC.Children.ParentChildrens.Select(pc => pc.ParentId).Distinct().Count() == context.Parents.Count()
            from childLocation in pToC.Children.ChildrenLocalizations
            where childLocation.Language == "en"
            select new { pToC.Children.ChildrenId, childLocation.Name }).Distinct();
```

Comment: This won't work: where child.ParentChildrens.Select(pc=>pc.ParentId).Distinct().Count() == context.Parents.Count(). And I am not sure why you are using context.Chldren

Comment: Imagine the following records (P1, C1), (P2, C1), (P2, C2), (P3, C1), (P3, C3) ... The only children that has association to all parents is C1. So first I need to check in ParentChildren table which ChildrenIds has a record with all ParentIds

Comment: @MiguelMoura A sorry didn't see the Given a IQueryable<Parent> in the question.

Comment: context.Parents at the start of my query is IQueryable<Parent>. context is Entity Framework DbContext.

Comment: @MiguelMoura I am missing something else then If the total of child's parents is equal to total number of parents then it has all parents right? In the example total p count for c1 is 3 and there are p1,p2,p3.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question but in the example (P1, C1), (P2, C1), (P2, C2), (P3, C1), (P3, C3) you can see that C1 is the only child that is associated to all parents. So the query result should return only 1 record with the ID of C1 and the Name of C1 taken from ChildrenLocalization. Even if C1 appears 3 times (associated to P1, P2 and P3) I only need result to return one record of C1. Does this help to clarify?

Comment: @MiguelMoura A Children ParentChildrens will have the count of 3 because it will have a P1 and P2 and P3 in the array. I added the distinct to return only one name for each child if there is a single en in the database and I only use the parents.

Comment: Not sure your using or Count works as the Count might be the same but the children different? And the Distinct in the end does not seem to work. Maybe because the object has two properties? I was only able to make it work using GroupBy and the the First one of the group.

Answer (score 1):

Given `IQueryable<Parent> parents`

```cs
parents
.SelectMany(p => p.ParentChildrens)
.Select(pc => pc.Children)
.Where(c => c.ParentChildrens
    .Select(pc => pc.ParentId)
    .OrderBy(i => i)
    .SequenceEqual(parents.Select(p => p.ParentId).OrderBy(i => i)))
.Select(c => new
{
    Id = c.ChildrenId,
    c.ChildrenLocalizations.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.Language == "en").Name
})
```

Comment: The operator ? is not allowed on a subquery ... And you removed an important part of the query which is select only the children that are associated to all parents.

Comment: Could you please expand on what you mean by the "children that are associated to all parents"? I'm thinking if you're querying from the `Parents` down to its `Children`, then they are associated.

Comment: I mean imagine the following records (P1, C1), (P2, C1), (P2, C2), (P3, C1), (P3, C3) ... The only children that has association to all parents is C1. So first I need to check in ParentChildren table which ChildrenIds has a record with all ParentIds ... Is it more clear now?

Comment: so if the database has 1000 parents, then the children that are associated to all 1000 parents?

Comment: I used context.Parents as an example. In fact I will use something like context.Parents.Where(x => ConditionToFilterParents) > Get Children that are associated to all parents resulting from the filter. But for the question in hand the Parents filter is irrelevant.

Comment: So yes, the children that are associated to all 1000 parents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191132/discussion-between-paolo-go-and-miguel-moura).

Comment: I tried your first suggestion as I though a nice approach the use of SequenceEqual but I got 0 items when I should get 3. Is some error on your query?

Comment: @MiguelMoura I think an `OrderBy` is needed. see edited answer.
I would also suggest looking at [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55491742/5588197)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 3 Parents, with Id 10, 11, 12
Suppose you have 3 Children with Id 20, 21, 22

ParentChildrens table:

```
ChildId | ParentId
  20         10
  20         11
  20         12
  21         10
  21         11
  22         10
  22         12
```

So Child 20 has Parents 10/11/12; Child 21 has Parent 10/11; Child 22 has Parents 10/12.

"Get the Children common to all Parents"; If that means: get the Children that have every available Parent in its collection of Parents, then it is easy to see that you only want Child 20, and you want this Child only once

> Because all Parent - Child relations are unique, we know that if there are X parents, that we want the Children that have exactly X parents.

You don't want all properties of these Children, you only want to "**get its name from ChildrenLocalization with Language="en**", Is there always zero or one such a name? If there are more which one should we take? Any name, or all Names?

Because we need to limit ourselves to all children that have a ParentCount equal to the number of parents, we also need to calculate the number of Parents per child

```
var childrenWithParentCount = dbContext.Children.Select(child => new
{
    // "get its name from ChildrenLocalization with Language="en"
    LocalizationName = child.ChildrenLocalizations
                            .Where(localization => localization.Language == "en")
                            .Select(localization => localizaition.Name)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

    // or if you want all names:
    LocalizationNames = child.ChildrenLocalizations
                             .Where(localization => localization.Language == "en")
                             .Select(localization => localizaition.Name)
                            .ToList;

    ParentCount = child.ParentChildren
                       .Select(parentChild => parentChild.ParentId)
                       .Count();
});
```

Now we don't want all these children, we only want those children that have a ParentCount equal to the number of Parents

```
var childrenWithAllParents = childrenWithParentCount
    .Where(child => !child.ParentCount == dbContext.Parents.Count());
```

Did you notice, that I only created IQueryable objects, I didn't execute any of the queries yet. To execute the query:

```
var result = childrenWithAllParents.ToList();
```

Some people like to impress others with one big LINQ statement; well here it is:

```
var result = dbContext.Children.Select(child => new
{
    LocalizationName = child.ChildrenLocalizations
          .Where(localization => localization.Language == "en")
          .Select(localization => localizaition.Name)
          .FirstOrDefault();

    ParentCount = child.ParentChildren
                       .Select(parentChild => parentChild.ParentId)
                       .Count();
})
.Where(child => !child.ParentCount == dbContext.Parents.Count())
.ToList();
```

Luckily your database management system is smart enough to remember the number of Parents, instead of calculating it again once per Child.

Comment: Answering your question Child 20 cannot have Parent 12 twice. The pair (ParentId, ChildId) in ParentChilds is unique.

Answer (score -1):

You need to split your calls from your grouping.

```
  List<Parent> result = context.Parents
                .Include(i => i.ParentChildrens)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Children)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.ChildrenLocalizations)
                .ToList();

            var finalResult = result.SelectMany(c => c.ParentChildrens, (o, j) =>
            {
                return new
                {
                    Id = j.ChildrenId,
                    Parent = o.ParentId,
                    Name = j.Children.ChildrenLocalizations.First(c => c.Language == "en").Name
                };
            });
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... Your query does not select Children common to All Parents. And when you do ToList you are loading everything into memory ...